# Rabbit listener annotation get queue name from yaml

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I currently have my rabbit listener annotation set as:

@RabbitListener(queues = "my-queue")

Is it not possible to pull in the queue name from my yaml file. The reason I want to do this, is so that I can change my queue to a test queue for my integration test, simply by changing the queue name in the yaml file.  It appears the annotation must accept a constant string, is there a way round this?  Thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is called `properties place holder` and can be done like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${myQueue.property}")
```

Where that `myQueue.property` is exactly declared in your yaml.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven

> The argument name, value, and type can be property placeholders (${...}) or SpEL expressions (#{...}). The name must resolve to a String; the expression for type must resolve to a Class or the fully-qualified name of a class. The value must resolve to something that can be converted by the DefaultConversionService to the type (such as the x-message-ttl in the above example).

Comment: what if i have to configure listener for multiple queues?

Comment: The `queues` is multi-value option, so you just can do this `queues = {"queue1", "queue2"}`

Comment: That's not what I want I should be able to to configure multiple queues without doing code change

Comment: Well, that's not clear from your plain comment. So, you need to specify those queues in the properties file for your application, and use the same properties placeholder mechanism, but wrapped into this SpEL expression: `"#{'${myQueue.property}'.split(',')}`